# Django create custom form renderer like .as_ul or .as_p

Tags: django, django-forms

I know there are so much questions about how to do a custom form renderer for Django, and I know that one of the best ways to do it is creating a form_snippet template with all the things we need.

But the problem is that I want to do it by the back-end side, I need to create a custom form renderer wich I can do something like {{ form.as_bootstrap }} in the template.

Someone knows the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create the method as_bootstrap in your form, but I highly recommend to you do your own [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/). In the other side, this question is widely open, what have you tried? please extends your question, otherwis, the comunity could close it.

Comment: Creating the method as_bootstrap in my form is the thing I need, thanks for your answer, I've tried with doing a form_snippet.html template with all the conditions to render the template properly. Why you recommend to write a templatetag inside of a function in the form?